# Why is my ScrollViewer's repeatbutton white at the bottom?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

So I am curious to why the scrollviewers repeatbutton at the bottom is white, it should be transparent, I didnt notice this until I resized my scrollviewer to fit perfectly, how do I change it's color to transparent?

[image]

I was looking throught the
 RepeatButton part of the style  and tried changing the background property but that didn't work either, it did nothing.

I even tried hiding it like so

```
<RepeatButton x:Name="PageDown"
                                            Command="ScrollBar.PageUpCommand"
                                            Opacity="0"
                                            Focusable="false" 
                                              Visibility="Hidden"/>
```

But that didnt work either, it was still there.

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">


    <Style x:Key="ScrollBarTrackThumb"
        TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                    <Grid x:Name="Grid">
                        <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                Width="Auto"
                                Height="Auto"
                                Fill="Transparent" />
                        <Border x:Name="CornerScrollBarRectangle"
                            CornerRadius="5"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                            VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                            Width="Auto"
                            Height="Auto"
                            Margin="0,1,0,1"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="Tag"
                                Value="Horizontal">
                            <Setter TargetName="CornerScrollBarRectangle"
                                Property="Width"
                                Value="Auto" />
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="CornerScrollBarRectangle"
                                Property="Height"
                                Value="6" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
        <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled"
            Value="false" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground"
            Value="#ADABAB" />
        <Setter Property="Background"
            Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="Width"
            Value="7" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
                    <Grid x:Name="GridRoot"
                        Width="7"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="0.00001*" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Track x:Name="PART_Track"
                            Grid.Row="0"
                            IsDirectionReversed="true"
                            Focusable="false">
                            <Track.Thumb>
                                <Thumb x:Name="Thumb"
                                    Background="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                    Style="{DynamicResource ScrollBarTrackThumb}" />
                            </Track.Thumb>
                            <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                                <RepeatButton x:Name="PageUp"
                                            Command="ScrollBar.PageDownCommand"
                                            Opacity="0"
                                            Focusable="false"/>
                            </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                            <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                                <RepeatButton x:Name="PageDown"
                                            Command="ScrollBar.PageUpCommand"
                                            Opacity="0"
                                            Focusable="false" />
                            </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                        </Track>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger SourceName="Thumb"
                                Property="IsMouseOver"
                                Value="true">
                            <Setter Value="{DynamicResource ButtonSelectBrush}"
                                TargetName="Thumb"
                                Property="Background" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger SourceName="Thumb"
                                Property="IsDragging"
                                Value="true">
                            <Setter Value="{DynamicResource DarkBrush}"
                                TargetName="Thumb"
                                Property="Background" />
                        </Trigger>

                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled"
                                Value="false">
                            <Setter TargetName="Thumb"
                                Property="Visibility"
                                Value="Collapsed" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="Orientation"
                                Value="Horizontal">
                            <Setter TargetName="GridRoot"
                                Property="LayoutTransform">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <RotateTransform Angle="-90" />
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                            <Setter TargetName="PART_Track"
                                Property="LayoutTransform">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <RotateTransform Angle="-90" />
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                            <Setter Property="Width"
                                Value="Auto" />
                            <Setter Property="Height"
                                Value="8" />
                            <Setter TargetName="Thumb"
                                Property="Tag"
                                Value="Horizontal" />
                            <Setter TargetName="PageDown"
                                Property="Command"
                                Value="ScrollBar.PageLeftCommand" />
                            <Setter TargetName="PageUp"
                                Property="Command"
                                Value="ScrollBar.PageRightCommand" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

And the actual scrollviewer

```
<ScrollViewer  Height="380"
                       Margin="10">

            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MessageViewModel.Messages}"
                      x:Name="MyListView"
                      Background="Transparent"
                      BorderThickness="0"
                      Height="380">

                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <WrapPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Message}"
                                       FontFamily="Consolas"
                                       Foreground="#61d73d"
                                       TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                        </WrapPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

Comment: As a note, do not put a ListView in a ScrollViewer. ListView already supports scrolling, and an outer ScrollViewer breaks [virtualization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/optimizing-performance-controls).

Comment: So I would have to style the scrollviewer for the Listview instead?

Comment: Yes, in a ControlTemplate for the ListView. However, that's complex.

Comment: I would not reproduce the issue with your code, no white square. Are you sure this is due to the Repeat button? I always use Snoop to investigate the visual tree in such cases.

Answer (score 0):

like Klaus, I think the issue is not with your repeatButton. Rather, you see the (white) background through your repeatButton.

try putting a red rectangle just behind your scrollButton to see the outcome
or even better : use snoop to check this kind of issue.

but also, Clemens is right : style/template the scrollviewer inside the listView, rather than outside.